# Add cursor to ending HTML tag shortcut

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want a keybinding which will automatically add a cursor to ending tag for HTML in vscode.

Such that `<h3>` tag closes with `</h3>`, If I want to change `<h3>` to `<h4>`, I want to change closing tag also by any way to add a cursor at ending tag too.

Please help me, I am new to code in vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a special keybinding, there is a setting you can enable:

`Editor: Linked Editing`

so that when you click inside one tag, a curor is added to the matching tag.

(same as `"editor.linkedEditing": true,` in your settings.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple script. And css

```js
//select all h3 elements
document.querySelectorAll('h3').forEach( element => {
  //create new h4 element
  const newElement = document.createElement('h4');

  //set the inner html to the original h3 element 
  newElement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

  //take all attributes from original element and assign them to the new one
  Array.from(element.attributes).forEach( attr => {
    newElement.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue)
  })

  //replace the node in the dom
  element.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, element);
})
```

```css
h4 {cursor: not-allowed;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>


<h2>this is h2 heading</h2>
<h3 >this is h3 heading</h3>
<h4>this is h4 heading</h4>





</body>
</html> 

<script>

</script>
```